# MySQL getting duplicate rows on Left outer Join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a count of events per day including days with no data from my database, I have created a calendar table, and have tried all the suggestions I have found, but for some reason I keep getting double the number of events for each day. below is the query I've been playing with.

```
 SELECT DAY(c.datefield) as date, COUNT(s.timestamp) as count
FROM calendar c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Seizures s ON (DATE(s.timestamp) = c.datefield)
WHERE c.datefield LIKE '2012-11-%'
GROUP BY c.datefield
```

If anyone can help prevent me from banging my head on the desk some more it would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE:

If i do a straightup count query without trying to use the JOIN for filling in dates that have no data I get the correct count of entries. It is only when trying to join that the count doubles for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT ??

Comment: Can you verify you have only 30 records for this month in your calendar table?

Comment: Show us the schema of `Seizures` and `calendar`.

Comment: is Seizures.timestamp is a timestamp or datetime?

Comment: So, just to be clear, `COUNT(s.timestamp) as count` is returning twice the expected number, but you've got the correct number of rows?

Comment: Yes the correct number of rows are in the database, it is just the count returning double the count. I think it has something to do with the Left outer join but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @PinnyM what do you mean only 30 records there are multiple records per day, and for the days which there are no records, I am using the Left outer join to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I was referring to the `calendar` table specifically. `seizures` can be expected to have more than 1 (or zero) - but your base calendar should have only 30 days (or you can simulate this with a DISTINCT subquery).

Comment: @PinnyM the calendar table was generated using a function it has as many day entries for each month ie. february 28, december 31. If i do a query on just the calendar table with a LIKE '2012-11-%' I get 30 rows of dates.

Comment: So a query like `SELECT * FROM calendar c WHERE c.datefield LIKE '2012-11-%'` gives you 30 rows?

Comment: @PinnyM I think you lead me to the solution, apparently somehow my calendar table rows got duplicated. This all worked fine a month ago I am not really sure what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on these results, it seems that your `calendar` table contains duplicate rows.  You can check this by running:

```
SELECT datefield, COUNT(*) FROM calendar
WHERE datefield LIKE '2012-11-%'
GROUP BY datefield
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If any rows are returned, then you have duplicates that need to addressed before your query will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my calendar table had all of its entries duplicated somehow this is what was causing the doubling of counts, @PinnyM lead me to figuring out this solution.

Thanx for the help.